# Firestore: Update fields in nested objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can one update fields in a document's nested object? The documentation indicated dot notation but how do you achieve the update with a variable as the object name?

Structure is like: `collection("fruits").doc("as867f56asd")`

```
name: "banana"
abc-variable: 
    description:"blah"
    qty: 1
```

I want to update document `as867f56asd`'s `abc-variable.qty` = 2

My JavaScript requires the use of a variable for the object name.

I can't figure out bracket notation for the update. Is `.set{merge:true}` req'd?

Here is the code I've tried so far (rough paste):

```
qty = evt.target.value;
//create a string
var obj = firebase.firestore.FieldPath(item).quantity;
//str = item + '.quantity';
//obj[str] = qty;
// var myUpdate = {};
// myUpdate['${item}.quantity'] = qty;
//var obj = [item]["quantity:"] = qty;
console.log("item is " + item);
//var obj = {"'" + item + "'.quantity" : qty};
//obj[item]["quantity"] = qty;
console.log("qty is " + qty);
orderRef.update (
    {obj:2}
    //{"quantity":qty}
    //[item + '.quantity']: qty
    //[`favorites.${key}.color`] = true
    // ['${item}.quantity'] : qty
    //[`hello.${world}`]:
    //{[objname]}.value = 'value';
    //['favorites.' + key + '.color']: true
    //[item]["quantity"] = qty // err:reqd 2 args
    //item["quantity"] = qty
    //"favorites.color": "Red"
    //{"`item`.quantity": qty}
    //{"quantity":qty}
)
```

Comment: Hey Ron. Can you show the code that you tried? I think yuo're looking for something like `values[abc-variable+".qty"] = 2`, but it's easier to answer if I see what you've done already.

Comment: inside the `.update(` IDE says `values` is not defined. If I wrap it in `{}` it says `Unexpected token [`. If I declare `values = {}` prior to the update, the IDE takes it and it passes linting but browser console throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined` Doing: `orderRef.update (values[item+".quantity"] = qty)`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It seems like I would need to nail a type of reference to the field (which is an object) and then from there, update a specific property. `FieldPath` or even defining a reference using URLencoding `\fruits\abc-123doc\obj-field-var` but I can't figure it out. I bout to give up and just re-write the whole document to update a single field. I know that works...

Comment: This `myUpdate['${item}.quantity'] = qty;` should probably be ``myUpdate[`${item}.quantity`] = qty;``. So with backticks around the string, since that's the JavaScript syntax for string interpolation.

Comment: What is `item` in the code you provided?

Comment: it's just a string, it's a part number / part identifier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the update you're trying to do:

```
let qty = 2
orderRef.update({"abc-variable.qty": qty});
```

But then where `abc-variable` is the value of a variable, you would do:

```
let qty = 2
let variable = "abc-variable";
var values = {};
values[variable] = qty;
orderRef.update(values);
```

**Update**

This code updates only the favorites:

```
var variableObjectName = "favorites";
var qty = Date.now(); // just so it changes every time we run
var field = {quantity:qty};
var obj = {};
obj[variableObjectName] = field; 
ref.update(obj);
```

It does not remove any other properties on the document.

**Update 2**

To update a single field in a nested objected, use `.` to address the field:

```
ref.update({ "favorites.quantity": Date.now() });
```

See the [documentation on how to update fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

**Update 3**

To perform a deep update of a field whose name is stored in a variable:

```
var name = "favorites";
var update = {};
update[name+".quantity"] = Date.now();
ref.update(update);
```

Once again shown in: https://jsbin.com/wileqo/edit?js,console

Comment: I challenge you to try to `.update` a single field of an object stored in a Firestore document where a variable is used as the stored object's name. If you can do it, I'll mail you [anyone] a free hightechtele.com BIC lighter. srsly.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the help. Notice how the other object properties are deleted after the `.update`? See updated jsbin -> https://jsbin.com/decizubuyi/edit?js,console ...could u make this work, just want to update `quantity` property only and leave other properties alone.

Comment: Sorry Ron, I can't reproduce what you're saying. The only time my entire document was overwritten was when you called `ref.set()` in your code. Once I updated your code in https://jsbin.com/xibodoc/1/edit?js,console to remove the `set()` it maintains all other fields, no matter how often I call `update()`.

Comment: not the entire document, the entire nested object. Updating a single property of a nested object (without having the other nested object's properties deleted) is the issue/problem. Notice the document in my jsbin included a nested object with 2 properties, `name` and `quantity`. Yours shows a nested object with a single property.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. That quite simple: `ref.update({ "favorites.quantity ": Date.now() })`. See the [documentation on how to update fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: Precisely, but "favorites.quantity" is not `[variableObjectName] + ".quantity"`. That's the question: how to do this with bracket notation (not dot notation which does not allow for variables) so that a variable name can be used to refer to the nested object.